# Bootstrap Typeahead - don't autoselect first item?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm using [this fork of the Twitter Bootstrap typeahead library](https://gist.github.com/1866577), which allows asynchronous data sources as well as onselect events. It's working really well for me so far, but when a user tabs out of the field (i.e. doesn't actively select a drop down entry), the onselect event is fired (which in my case, redirects the user to another page). Is there any way I can stop the onselect event being fired if a user doesn't click? Here's what I've got so far (in CoffeeScript):

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#inspection_name').typeahead(
    source: (typeahead, query) ->
      $.ajax(
        url: "/inspections/search.json?name="+query
        success: (data) =>
          return_list = []
          $(data.results.inspections).each ->
            return_list.push("<span data-url='" + this.uri + "/edit'>" + this.name + ", " + this.town + "</span>") 

          typeahead.process(return_list)
      )

    onselect: (obj) =>
      window.location.href = $(obj).attr("data-url")
  )
```

Comment: I've actually answered my own question now. I've made a small edit to the original Gist to stop the default behaviour when tabbing. [You can see my adjustments, together with a Diff here](https://gist.github.com/1977953)

Comment: Thank you, that Gist was really useful.  If you make your comment into an answer I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I answered my own question, and put the adjustments in this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/1977953

Comment: See my [answer to a similar SO-question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16399228/517336) for another solution.

Answer (score 6):

For the default Bootstrap, this will work:

```
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.render = function (items) {

var that = this;

items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
  i = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item);
  i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item));
  return i[0];
});

this.$menu.html(items);
return this;
};
```

Somewhere after including bootstrap.(min.)js

Comment: thanks for this, i've expanded on it to have some hacks to make the tab key cycle through options as well:
https://gist.github.com/peterschilling/5118516

Comment: I'm using the standard, default Bootstrap and this works except it also introduces a bug where when I hit the "ENTER" key, it no longer performs the search (I have to manually click the submit button I have in place).

Comment: Just found this link (http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/overriding-bootstrap-typeahead-to-not-initially-select/) which explains the problem I found as noted above and how to correctly fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the attribute in angular-bootstrap typehead

```
typeahead-focus-first="false"
```

Similar option availble for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

All credit should go to @jrochkind but I wanted to put the answer from [Bibliographic Wilderness: Overriding bootstrap typeahead to not initially select](http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/overriding-bootstrap-typeahead-to-not-initially-select/) here for more clarity.

Add this somewhere after `bootstrap.js`:

```
/**
 * Makes it so the first typeahead result isn't auto selected
 *
 * @author Jonathan Rochkind
 * @url http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/overriding-bootstrap-typeahead-to-not-initially-select/
 */
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.select = function() {
    var val = this.$menu.find('.active').attr('data-value');
    if (val) {
        this.$element
            .val(this.updater(val))
            .change();
    }
    return this.hide()
};
var newRender = function(items) {
    var that = this

    items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
        i = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item);
        i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item));
        return i[0];
    });

    this.$menu.html(items);
    return this;
};
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.render = newRender;
```